# Etymology of "at large"

Tags: etymology, idioms

> The killer is still at large.

Where does the meaning of *[at large](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/at_large)* (*not captured; free*) come from? Besides being *big* I know that *large* means also *wide in range and involving many things*. Is there any connection between that meaning and the idiom?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=large&searchmode=none) says:

> c.1200, "bountiful, inclined to give or spend freely," also, of areas, "great in expanse," from O.Fr. large "broad, wide; generous, bounteous," ... An older sense of "liberated, free from restraining influence" is preserved in *at large* (late 14c.)

Wiktionary references the Old French *au large* ("at liberty", now means *off* in the sense of *offshore/off the coast* or *abroad*) in the [Etymology section](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/at_large#Etymology) of its *at large* entry.  I checked Google books, and in [one commentary on Paradise Lost](http://books.google.com/books?id=SuXWhYuz3NsC&pg=PA96&lpg=PA96&dq=Old%20French%20au%20large%20at%20liberty&source=bl&ots=wzd-YnvoCO&sig=PVBdXpX_zkPixu6lGafs3JZpayI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=v49sT8mtEenx0gGSxrG3Bg&ved=0CEwQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=Old%20French%20au%20large%20at%20liberty&f=false), *at large* is discussed:

[image]

The old meaning of large (*liberated*) may be found, then, to be preserved in *at large* as well as in the French.

Comment: So 'at large' is connected with 'largesse' ...http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=largesse